# ODE with piecewise continuous force

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am trying to solve the following ODE: $$
y''(t)+y(t)=f(t), \quad y(0)=0, \quad y'(0)=0, \quad t\geq 0,
$$
where $$
f(t):=\begin{cases}1 &\hbox{if} \quad 2k\leq t<2k+1,
\\ -1 & \hbox{if} \quad 2k+1\leq t<2k+2, \end{cases}
$$
for every $k=1,...,9$, and $f(t)=1$ for $t\geq 20$. I have been trying to use Laplace transform to solve it but I am not sure how to express the right-hand side. In concrete, I do not know how to compute $\mathcal{L}(f)[c]$, where $\mathcal{L}$ stands for the Laplace transform. Does anyone knows how to do it? I woul really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to apply the Laplace transform you need to re-write the right-hand side in term of step functions: $$
f(t)=H(t-2)-2H(t-3)+2H(t-4)-2H(t-5)\pm...-2H(t-19)+2H(t-20),
$$
where $H(t)$ is the function defined by $$
H(t)=\begin{cases}1 & \hbox{if} \quad t\geq 0,
\\ 0 &\hbox{if} \quad t<0.\end{cases}
$$
Thus, $H(t-2)$ represents the steps function at $t=2$. Notice that, after the first step function $H(t-2)$, it is important to put the factor $2$ in front of all the remaining step functions. This because you need to consider a factor of "$1$" to remove the previous step function (and then jumping, for instance, from $1$ to $0$) and another factor of "$1$" to jump from $0$ to $-1$. Finally, by linearity of the Laplace transform you have $$
\mathcal{L}(f)[c]=\mathcal{L}(H(t-2))[c]-2\mathcal{L}(H(t-3))[c]\pm...-2\mathcal{L}(H(t-19))[c]+2\mathcal{L}(H(t-20))[c],
$$
where each $\mathcal{L}(H(t-n))$ is easily computable by basic Laplace transform tricks.  I let you the details and I hope my answer help you.